# Toggle between to div's using anchor Tag Using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

```css
#second{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
<h1>First Div</h1>
<a href="#second">Go to Div2</a>
</div>

<div id="second">
<h1>Second</h1>
<a href="#first">Go to Div1</a>
</div>
```

Initially, Div2 will not be visible to User when user clicks on Go to Div2, he should able to see Div2 content, when user clicks on Go to Div1 he should able to able see Div1 content, At a time only one div content should be visible

Comment: Try using onClick events to add and remove a class which then hides it using CSS

Comment: @Hive7 ok I will try

Comment: @MandapatiGanesh, Hope this helps you https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/JjWGRbm

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change () {
  let first = document.getElementById('first');
  let second = document.getElementById('second');
  
  if (first.style.display === "none") {
    first.style.display = "block";
    second.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    second.style.display = "block";
    first.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
<h1>First Div</h1>
<a href="#second" onclick="change()">Go to Div2</a>
</div>

<div id="second">
<h1>Second</h1>
<a href="#first" onclick="change()">Go to Div1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some index.js or whatever:

```
const divToggle = document.querySelectorAll(".div-toggle");

divToggle.forEach((element) => {
  let target = element.dataset.target;
  let targetElement = document.querySelector(`#${target}`);
  element.onclick = () => {
    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.classList.add("visible");
      element.parentElement.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  };
});
```

and in your css, you would have something like this:

```
.div-collapsible {
  display: none;
}

.div-collapsible.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

and finally, the html:

```
<div id="first-div" class="div-collapsible visible">
   <h1>First Div</h1>
   <a class="div-toggle" href="#second" data-target="second-div">Go to Div2</a>
</div>
<div id="second-div" class="div-collapsible">
   <h1>Second</h1>
   <a class="div-toggle" href="#first" data-target="first-div">Go to Div1</a>
</div>
```

Initially, the div with the class `visible` will be shown. All other collapsible divs are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Use provided javascript, and add onClick attribute to your links.

```css
    #second{
      display:none;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="first">
      <h1>First Div</h1>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunc()">Go to Div2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
      <h1>Second</h1>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunc()">Go to Div1</a>
    </div>
```

```js
function myFunc(){
  var first = document.getElementById("first"),
      second = document.getElementById("second");
  if(first.style.display == "none"){
    first.style.display = "block";
    second.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    first.style.display = "none";
    second.style.display = "block";
  }
  
}
```